# Initramfs Unpacking Failed

Tags: boot, vmware, kali-linux, kernel, initramfs-tools

I am using VMware 15.x on my Windows 10 machine to boot into Kali 2018.3a. I messed around it and I have come to this error. So every time I power on to my VM, this screen appears:

[image: Initramfs problem]

What I have tried till now:

I tried booting with CD/DVD of Kali 2018.3a iso. Now after booting it is looking like a new Kali machine. I think I have to mount the file system, but I have no clue what to do next or what the solution is.

Comment: What the app name and version which are you trying to create that Kali VM?

Comment: VMWARE 15.X.. It was already created. I messed it up somehow.

Comment: Can you boot your VM on [Recovery Mode](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/)?

Comment: @jluizsouzadev . I successfully booted to a Kali iso . Now it looks like a new Kali machine . Any idea what I have to do next to clear this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Boot your VM with **[Kali Linux 64-bit (NetInstaller)](https://cdimage.kali.org/kali-2020.2/kali-linux-2020.2-installer-netinst-amd64.iso)**
2. On Kali menu go to **Advanced options->Rescue Mode**
3. Go to screen where you asked the follow question **"Device to use as root file system"**, then enter the partition that you defined as **"root file system"** during the Kali installation on VM.(Note: for example, I'll consider that you selected **"/dev/sda1"** from this point)
4. Then, select **"Execute a shell in the installer environment"**
5. Then, select **"Continue"**
6. Then, run the following commands:

   **mount --bind /dev /target/dev**

   **mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc**

   **mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys**

   **chroot /target**

   **apt reinstall -y linux-image-amd64**

   **apt reinstall -y drakut**

   **apt reinstall -y grub2**

   **grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

   **update-grub**

   **grub-install /dev/sda**

   **exit**

   **umount /target/dev /target/proc /target/sys**

   **reboot**

References:

- [How to Boot to Recovery Mode (Safe Mode) in Ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/boot-recovery-mode-ubuntu/)
- [How to Fix a Broken Initrd Image in Linux](https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/fixing-broken-initrd-image-linux/)
- [CentOS / RHEL 6 : How to rebuild Initial Ramdisk Image](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-6-how-to-rebuild-initial-ramdisk-image/)